# Android Retrofit2 Kotlin can't set list value equal to Response

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, kotlin, retrofit2

I'm having problems getting data from the Facebook API inside a varaiable. In my main activity I call `viewModel.getFeed()`. The logger returns null, but OkHttp returns the response I want. How can I populate the list with this response data?

**FacebookAPIService**

```
interface FacebookAPIService {
    // Get all the english movies in given year
    @GET("USER_ID/feed?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN")
    fun getUserFeed(): Call<NewsItemData>
}
```

**FacebookAPI**

```
class FacebookAPI {
    companion object {

        private const val baseUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/v5.0/"

        /**
         * @return [FacebookAPIService] The service class off the retrofit client
         */
        fun createApi(): FacebookAPIService {

            val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY))
                .build()

            // Create retrofit instance
            val facebookApi = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()

            // Return the retrofit FacebookAPIService
            return facebookApi.create(FacebookAPIService::class.java)
        }
    }
}
```

**NewsRepository**

```
class NewsRepository(context: Context) {
    private val facebookApi: FacebookAPIService = FacebookAPI.createApi()

    fun getUserFeed() = facebookApi.getUserFeed()
...
```

**MainActivityViewModel**

```
class MainActivityViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    private val newsItemsRepository = NewsRepository(application.applicationContext)
    val newsItems = MutableLiveData<List<NewsItem>>()

    private fun getFeed() {
        newsItemsRepository.getUserFeed().enqueue(object : Callback<NewsItemData?> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<NewsItemData?>, response: Response<NewsItemData?>) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    newsItems.value = response.body()!!.results
                    Log.d("response", newsItems.value.toString())
                } else {
                    error.value = "An error has occurred: ${response.errorBody().toString()}"
                    Log.e("response", response.toString())
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<NewsItemData?>, t: Throwable) {
                error.value = t.message
            }
        })
    }
}
```

**NewsItem**

```
@Parcelize
@Entity(tableName = "news_item")
data class NewsItem(
    @SerializedName("message") var message: String,
    @SerializedName("story") var story: String,
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Long? = null
) : Parcelable
```

**NewsItemData**

```
class NewsItemData {
    var results: List<NewsItem>? = null
}
```

To give some more background my response looks something like this:

```
{
   "data": [
      ...
      {
         "created_time": "some timestamp",
         "id": "some id"
      },
      {
         "message": "some messge",
         "created_time": "some timestamp",
         "id": "some id"
      }
      ...
   ],
   "paging": {
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: try to log `response.body` not log `newsitem.value` you can change to this `if (response.isSuccessful) {Log.d("response", response.body().string()) .....}` and use `body().string` instead of `body().toString` at logger

Comment: @adipurnama string() is not a recognized function

Comment: oh...but at my code is working,i'm moving comment to answer bro...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you have to add a `@SerializedName` to the NewsItemData `results` field.

**NewsItemData**

```
class NewsItemData {
    @SerializedName("data") var results: List<NewsItem>? = null
}
```

Otherwise the JSON array won't be correctly mapped to a list as you intended.

Comment: You were right. I didn't notice I hadn't annotated it. I've reached my vote limit, so I will upvote your answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

This my code for response parse json

```
if (response.isSuccessful) {
    response.body()?.let { body ->
        results=body
        Log.d("API RESULT"," $results")
    }
} else {
    var bodyError=response.errorBody()?.string()?:"Error connection with server"
    try {
        //use this to parse json at error response
        val message=JSONObject(bodyError)
        bodyError = if (message.has("message")) 
                        message.getString("message")
                    else 
                        "Error connection with server"
    }catch (ex: JSONException) {
        Log.e("API NOT JSON"," $bodyError")
    }
    Log.e("API ERROR"," $bodyError")
}
```

Hope this help